# How to remove ambiguous reference between two interfaces in same class in C# ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, interface

how to remove ambiguous reference between two interfaces in  same class in C# ASP.Net?

I have a class which is implementing an interface ISecurity. ISecurity interface is present in two different namespaces. I have another interface in the same class which is from one of those two interface. So Isucurity interface getting ambiguous reference error. How to fix that?

Comment: `namespaceName.ISecurity`

Comment: Read through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by simply giving the namespace explicitly.
For Ex: In namespace NameSpace1 you have ISecurity and in NameSpace2 you also have ISecurity. To use both just give it this way.

NameSpace1.ISecurity and NameSpace2.ISecurity.

Answer (score 1):

You can alias at least one of the namespaces or both of the types. Aliasing the types:

```
using ISecurityA = NameSpaceA.ISecurity;
using ISecurityB = NameSpaceB.ISecurity;

...

ISecurityB x = new WhateverImplementsISecurityInNameSpaceB();
```

Aliasing at least one namespace means that the other is the default:

```
using NameSpaceA; //default
using NSB = NameSpaceB;


ISecurity a = new WhateverImplementsISecurityInNameSpaceA(); //default is namespace a
NSB.ISecurity b = new WhateverImplementsISecurityInNameSpaceB(); //have to be explicit about b
```